# Convert a value in a logarithmic sequence to a linear equivalent

Tags: exponential-function, linear-transformations

Sorry if im asking a silly question. Its been a while since varsity maths.

I have a logarithmic sequence ranging from [1 to 32]. It is a signal strength value from a modem.

I need to display this value as a linear percentage.

What sort of algorithm or maths function would I use to obtain the linear percentage equivalent of the logarithmic input.

So my functions input would be 1 to 32, and the output would range from 0 to 100.

ie `f(32) = 100`

I am not to sure what to map f(0) to, as there can't technically be a 0% signal strength connection because then there wouldn't be a connection?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want a linear $f$ such that $f(32) = 100$ and $f(0) = 0$, $f(x) = \frac{100}{32} x$. Note that this does not reflect the actualy "signal strength" percentage from signals (I assume you have it in $-x\ \mathrm {dB}$)

Comment: how would I reflect the 'actual' signal strength then?  Please see my edit regrading `f(0)`

Comment: @Zapnologica See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797920/how-to-convert-wifi-signal-strength-from-quality-percent-to-rssi-dbm) for the inverse operation (percent $\to$ dB). It shouldn't be hard to figure out the operations needed for dB $\to$ percent.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but they are converting exact db to percentage. My input range is only 1:32 . Or am I being daft?

Comment: @Zapnologica I'm really unsure why you wonder about mapping $0$ to $0\%$ if it's not even in your input range. The link describes both conversions for the usual WiFi strength RSSI and quality $\%$. With RSSI of $-100\ \mathrm{dB}$ you are unlikely to get a working connection, so $0\%$ is justified as a quality of that. If you can clarify what you want, maybe I can help you more.

Comment: I am unsure because there is no f(0) . My input range is from 1:32. Yes maybe f(0) is 0% . But in my application I will just never user f(0). So if f(0) = 0% is needed to do the conversion. Then that makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to map $0$ to $0\%$ and $32$ to $100\%$. In that case, all you need to do is multiply your number with $\frac{100}{32}$ to get the percentage.

For example, $f(16) = 16\cdot\frac{100}{32} = 50$.

Comment: however f(16) is not 50% because the input sequence is logarithmic?

Comment: @Zapnologica Then I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: What should f(16) be then?